# the boundedness of the derivative operator

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

I need to show that the linear operator

$ \frac{d}{dx}: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow L^2(-\infty,\infty)$
is bounded with respect to the inner product

$(f,g) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {f(t) \overline{g(t)}+f'(t)\overline{g'(t)}} dt $

on $\mathcal{D}$.

Here, $\mathcal{D}$ represents the space of differentiable functions $f$, where $f, f' \in L^2(-\infty,\infty)$.

My work

To prove the boundedness, I work on $||\frac{d}{dx}f||^2$ which is equal to
$||f'||_2^2 +||f''||_2^2$ which takes me to the norm of the second derivative. So, I tried to rewrite it in terms of norm of $f$ and $f'$ using integration by parts, but this does not seems work as parts gives integrals with third derivative terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to give that inner product to $\mathcal{D}$. This makes sense, since this is the inner product on the Sobolev space $H^1$ (the inner product doesn't make sense on all of $L^2$, as not every function in $L^2$ has a weak derivative in $L^2$), and $\frac{d}{dx}:H^1\rightarrow L^2$ boundedly. Indeed, $$\left\|\frac{d}{dx}f\right\|_{L^2}\leq \|f\|_{L^2}+\left\|\frac{d}{dx}f\right\|_{L^2}\leq \sqrt{2}\|f\|_{H^1},$$ which proves boundedness.

Comment: how did you get the inequality? did you use the integration by parts? For the equality, should they be $||f||_{L^2} ^2 +||\frac{d}{dx} f||_{L^2}^2 = ||f||_{H^1}^2 $ ??

Comment: The first inequality is true since all that I did was add $\|f\|_{L^2}$, which is non-negative. As for your next question, I realized that I'm using an equivalent definition of the $H^1$ norm, I will edit. It's essentially, the equivalence of the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Equivalence

Comment: I see!
Thank you very much!